# What's wrong with my drop constraint syntax?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I'm new to mySQL. I have SSMS open right now and I have a tabled labeled "Autos" and a column labeled "Year". I did this long ago so I know I have a constraint on year such that I can input 2015 but not 2016, I believe it's (Year < 2016) but I don't know how to change it.

I have this code:

```
ALTER TABLE Autos
DROP CONSTRAINT Year < 2016
```

But I get the following error:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '<'.

Is there a way I can improve the syntax, or even better, remove ALL the constraints on here? I can't get my VB.NET program to run without getting an exception if I can't get this fixed!

The INSERT statement conflicted with the CHECK constraint "CK__Autos__Year__15502E78". The conflict occurred in database "classified", table "dbo.Autos", column 'Year'.
The statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use : 
ALTER TABLE autos DROP CONSTRAINT CK__Autos__Year__15502E78;

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the check constraint drop:

ALTER TABLE Autos
DROP CHECK CK__Autos__Year__15502E78

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CHECK'.